# Theano - how to override gradient for part of op graph

Tags: deep-learning, theano

I have a rather complex model at hand. The model have multiple parts with *linear* structure:

```
y = theano.tensor.dot(W,x) + b
```

I want to build a optimizer that uses a custom rule to compute gradient for all *linear* structure, while keeping other operations intact. **What's the easiest way to override gradient ops for all linear part of my model?** Preferably no need to write a new Op.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I spent some time working on a [PR](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/5255) (<del>not merged as of Jan 13 2017</del> already merged) for Theano, which gives user ability to partially override gradient of a `theano.OpFromGraph` instance. The override is done with symbolic graph so you still gain the full benefit of theano optimization.

Typical use cases:

- Numerical safety consideration
- Rescale/clipping gradient
- Specialized gradient routine like Riemannian natural gradient

To make an Op with overriding gradient:

1. Make the needed compute graph
2. Make an OpFromGraph instance (or a python function) for gradient of your Op
3. Make an OfG instance your Op, and set `grad_overrides` argument
4. call OfG instance to build your model

Defining an OpFromGraph is like compiling a theano function, with some difference:

- No support for `updates` and `givens` (As of Jan 2017)
- You get an symbolic Op instead of a numerical function

Example:

```
'''
This creates an atan2_safe Op with smoothed gradient at (0,0)
'''
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T

# Turn this on if you want theano to build one large graph for your model instead of precompiling the small graph.
USE_INLINE = False
# In a real case you would set EPS to a much smaller value
EPS = 0.01

# define a graph for needed Op
s_x, s_y = T.scalars('xy')
s_darg = T.scalar(); # backpropagated gradient
s_arg = T.arctan2(s_y, s_x)
s_abs2 = T.sqr(s_x) + T.sqr(s_y) + EPS
s_dx = -s_y / s_abs2
s_dy = s_x / s_abs2

# construct OfG with gradient overrides
# NOTE: there are unused inputs in the gradient expression,
#     however the input count must match, so we pass    
#     on_unused_input='ignore'
atan2_safe_grad = th.OpFromGraph([s_x, s_y, s_darg], [s_dx, s_dy], inline=USE_INLINE, on_unused_input='ignore')
atan2_safe = th.OpFromGraph([s_x, s_y], [s_arg], inline=USE_INLINE, grad_overrides=atan2_safe_grad)

# build graph using the new Op
x, y = T.scalar(), T.scalar()
arg = atan2_safe(x, y)
dx, dy = T.grad(arg, [x, y])
fn = th.function([x, y], [dx, dy])
fn(1., 0.) # gives [-0.0, 0.99099]
fn(0., 0.) # gives [0.0, 0.0], no more annoying nan!
```

NOTE: the `theano.OpFromGraph` is still largely experimental, expect bugs.